# Are angels perfect

Tags: malaikah

I want to know if angels are perfect. I know that they don’t have free will. What does perfect mean in Islam. Does it mean no sins. Does it mean no mistakes and faults? Angel gabreel made a fault one time. He thought that he was suppose to worship Allah more, greater, and better.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angels_in_Islam

Comment: sorry Wikipedia is not reliable

Comment: "Perfect" is not an Islamic term. It's just an English word. So, "What does perfect mean in Islam" seems to be a meaningless question. Rather, you need to tell us what you mean by perfect in this question.

Comment: Jibril stuffing mud of Nile into phaoroahs throat. Angel's questioning Allah when he created Adam. Indicate something, you can reframe your question accordingly

Comment: @ItzFaiz when did Angel Gabriel make mistake?

Comment: Oh ok nvevermind. I meant perfect as no sins?

Comment: Oh ok. Now I understand. There is no perfect except Allah. But wasn’t Muhammad SAW perfect.

Comment: How do you define perfect?

Answer (score 0):

Angels are supposed beings bringing messages from God to us.

Al-Baqarah 2:31-36

> And He taught Adam the names, all of them; then he presented them to
> the angels, and said, “Tell Me the names of these, if you are
> sincere.” They said, “Glory be to You! We have no knowledge except
> what You have taught us. It is you who are the Knowledgeable, the
> Wise.” He said, “O Adam, tell them their names.” And when he told them
> their names, He said, “Did I not tell you that I know the secrets of
> the heavens and the earth, and that I know what you reveal and what
> you conceal?” And We said to the angels, “Bow down to Adam.” They
> bowed down, except for Satan. He refused, was arrogant, and was one of
> the disbelievers. We said, “O Adam, inhabit the Garden, you and your
> spouse, and eat from it freely as you please, but do not approach this
> tree, lest you become wrongdoers.” But Satan caused them to slip from
> it, and caused them to depart the state they were in. We said, “Go
> down, some of you enemies of one another. And you will have residence
> on earth, and enjoyment for a while.”

At least, counting Iblis among the angels, there is no doubt that angels fail.

It is disputable whether Iblis was an angel (at least he would now only be an ex-angel anyway), and it does not say very much about real angels.

There is nothing in the Qur'an or the major Hadith interpretable in the sense that that they are perfect (whatever word would be used for this in Arabic). If you mean perfect to be that there is none to add, none can be perfect but God Alone.

P.S. Although not perfect, the article in Wikipedia may help you to make your question more specific and get a more specific answer

Comment: Satan is not an angel. And the verses you've quoted actually are evidence for the contrary to what you claim.

Comment: The initial sentence refers to the angels of God. I have put this in front before the passage cited because I didn't want to start with the citation. I said "supposed to", as Satan is said to have been among the angels that were supposed to serve God but turned to evil, as the most drastic example of imperfection.

Comment: Iblis is not an Angel, he is from Jinn. Quran 7:12, Iblis says he is superior because he was created from Fire. Whereas Angels were created from Light - Muslim 5722